# jQuery datepicker. How to insert datepicker.gif after input field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How to insert an image after the input field when using jQuery datepicker?

I expect to use the function: buttonImage.

```
My jQuery code:

        jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: 'http://finansraadet.opengate.dk/images/arrowH3.gif',
    //      dayNamesMin: ['man', 'tir', 'ons', 'tor', 'fre', 'lør', 'søn'],
    //      monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],
    //      yearRange: '2004:2015',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          minDate: new Date(1973, 1 - 1, 1)
        });
```

In the form there is an input field. But no image end up after it. The datepicker works just fine when clicking the input field.

What to do? Am I using it wrong?

BR. Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the showOn:'button' option. Your code works as is with this option switched on.

Comment: Thanks. Spot on! It worked as a charm. Im am sorry, but I cannot marks two answer as correct, so I (unfair) gave the checkmark to Bill Terry to help him increase his reputaion. Still a way to go before you will feel his breath in your neck ;-)

Comment: Changed my mind. I guess your answer is the most wright based on the jQuery I posted. Thanks for your help

Comment: To position the calendar/button image: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10240362/1351605

Answer (score 1):

Use the embed option with it.  Example:

```
 // Setup datepicker for Tasks dialog (high z-index) 
 // Start date
 $('.start-date').datepicker({
     showOn: 'button', 
     buttonImageOnly: true, 
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
     beforeShow: function (i, e) {
         var z = 2000;
         e.dpDiv.css('z-index', z);
     }  
  }).addClass("embed");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and example. The showOn: 'button' did the trick. I have not read about the embed option. I will look into what that is. Thanks for your help and example code.

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping out all the options except for `buttonImage`.  If that works, add them back in one at a time.

If that doesn't work, please post your HTML.

Also, check to make sure you're not calling `$.datepicker()` twice.