# How to Set the size & position of jquery Date picker calendar icon trigger image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i am using jquery date picker the calendar  icon trigger image near textbox is by default is on top i want to set the image size (height) same as textbox height please give me some suggestions
my code is

```
$(#textbox1).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "calendar_1.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true
)};
```

Comment: for example http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: Look for what the jqueryui generates, using firebug and see what are the classes they are using, with that you can give some css touch

Comment: You should create an `override.css` file, with the classes specified by the people below, and include it after the main jquery ui style sheet.  This way, you'll have a clear separation of your changes vs the original file.

Comment: This may not relate to your answer directly but in my case I was having a hidden field for the datepicker text box along with the textbox and that's why Image button was not aligning well with the textbox.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Inspecting the element with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), I got this:

```
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="http://xxxxx/officeprime/assets/img/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."/>
```

eg:
`button.ui-datepicker-trigger img`

You can then work with that CSS class `ui-datepicker-trigger`.

Answer (score 28):

Add custom CSS in your page

```
<style>
.ui-datepicker-trigger { position:relative;top:{}px ;right:{}px ; height:{}px }
 /* {} is the value according to your need */
</style>
```

Comment: This worked for me: `.ui-datepicker-trigger{position:relative;top:7px;`

Answer (score 12):

You can edit class .ui-datepicker-trigger with jQuery but it's important to make editing after datepicker function.

Example:

```
$(#textbox1).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "calendar_1.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true )};

$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").css("margin-bottom","-6px");
```

Comment: That's great. You made it so simple dear friend ;). I appreciated with thumbs up (y)

Answer (score 1):

None of this worked for me.  It appears that jQuery sets the height property of the image button when leaving the ready function.  So if you try to set the height property in the ready function it gets overwritten to 26px.  So I created a separate function to run in the onload event of the body tag.  It updates the height property of the button to what I want like this:

```
// sample jQuery datepicker button tag: <img style="margin: 0px; padding: 2px; height: 26px; vertical-align: bottom;" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" >
var oDateCell = oTableRow.cells[2];
var sDateCellHTML = oDateCell.innerHTML;
var sRevisedHTML = sDateCellHTML.replace("height: 26px;", "height: 13px;");
oDateCell.innerHTML = sRevisedHTML;
```

I did some more work on this and I discovered that the code above has a bug.  It causes the click event to fail and the calendar does not display when clicking the image.  I don't know why, but I found a better way that does work.  The method above was a clunky (lazy?) way of changing the style.  The correct way is like this:

```
            var oTableRow = oTable.rows[iRow];
            if (oTableRow.cells.length > 2)
            {
                var oDateCell = oTableRow.cells[2];
                if (oDateCell.childNodes.length > 1)
                {
                    var oImage = oDateCell.childNodes[1];
                    oImage.style.height = "13px";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply this CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own personalized image for the calendar icon then you can simply make the image of the size you want. For my case my input box's height was `24px` and the icon size was `16X16`. I just edited the size of the image and made it `24X24` and the problem was solved.