# how does a calendar pop up triggered by an image button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an example that when the focus is on the textbox, a calendar pops up.

```
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text="please select date" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

The above example works. But now I want to use a image button to pop up the calendar. So the code becomes:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        $("#<%= ImageOrderTime.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text="please select date" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
<asp:ImageButton Id="ImageOrderTime" ImageUrl="images/OrderTime.png" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

But when I click the image button, the calendar doesn't show up. What is wrong with it? thanks.

PS: Here is the definition of **datepicker**:

```
 e.fn.datepicker = function(t) {
    if (!this.length) return this;
    e.datepicker.initialized || (e(document).mousedown(e.datepicker._checkExternalClick), e.datepicker.initialized = !0),
    0 === e("#" + e.datepicker._mainDivId).length && e("body").append(e.datepicker.dpDiv);
    var i = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return "string" != typeof t || "isDisabled" !== t && "getDate" !== t && "widget" !== t ? "option" === t && 2 === arguments.length && "string" == typeof arguments[1] ? e.datepicker["_" + t + "Datepicker"].apply(e.datepicker, [this[0]].concat(i)) : this.each(function() {
        "string" == typeof t ? e.datepicker["_" + t + "Datepicker"].apply(e.datepicker, [this].concat(i)) : e.datepicker._attachDatepicker(this, t)
    }) : e.datepicker["_" + t + "Datepicker"].apply(e.datepicker, [this[0]].concat(i))
},
e.datepicker = new n,
e.datepicker.initialized = !1,
e.datepicker.uuid = (new Date).getTime(),
e.datepicker.version = "1.11.4",
e.datepicker,
```

I am quite new to JS/Jquery. not sure if I have provided enough info, and I also don't know why the calendar pops up. Please tell me if I need to provide other code.

Comment: Would you please give us the plain Html&JavaScript code?

Comment: Hi Terry, I have uploaded some more code.@Terry Wei

Comment: Is the answer below helps you?

Comment: It doesn't work. @Terry Wei

Comment: Is it because the image button refreshes the page?@Terry Wei

Comment: Yes, refresh the page is not what we want.

Comment: I tried to change the asp button into the html button but then its id cannot be identified in $(function()...);@ Terry Wei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `ImageButton`. Please remove it and use the code below

```
$(function() {
    $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: 'images/OrderTime.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: 'Select date',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Documentation: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot. Btw, how to set the position of this image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240278/how-to-set-the-size-position-of-jquery-date-picker-calendar-icon-trigger-image

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker should not work on img element.

You could do like below to show calendar on image click:

```
$("#<%= ImageOrderTime.ClientID %>").click(function(event){
    $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").click();
})
```

Like this way to show up the calendar while you click on the image.